# Perl, create hash of hashes tree from array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

So, I have next array of hashes:

```
my @arr = (
  #subways, "0" - superroot
  {id => "1",     parent_id => "0",     name => "subway 1"},
  #lines
  {id => "12642", parent_id => "1",     name => "no category"},
  {id => "12645", parent_id => "1",     name => "line 1"},
  #cars
  {id => "12646", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 1"},
  {id => "12646", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 1"},
  {id => "12647", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 2"},
  {id => "12647", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 2"},
  {id => "12679", parent_id => "1",     name => "separate cars"},
  {id => "12679", parent_id => "12642", name => "separate cars"},
  {id => "12643", parent_id => "1",     name => "ungrouped"},
  {id => "12643", parent_id => "12642", name => "ungrouped"}
);
```

and I heed to make a tree of them like:

```
subway->line->carriage
```

By the way, here's a problem. As you see - here's a "1" in doubling carriages, but I need line as parent_id. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It would help if you explain how 'subway'/'line'/'carriage' refers to your data, and how you would want your resultant structure to end up. But ideally, you'll give it a try yourself, and let us know what problems you're having, rather than ask someone to do your work for you.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow probably isn't the best place for your question.

Comment: While you have two answers already, a lot depends on what you want to do with the final data structure. You say *"I need to make a tree of them like `subway->line->carriage`"* but it could be said that the data you have already does that. Both of your answers sort the data by dependency and show a tree structure as a result of that sort, but their results are very different. If you can describe better how you intend to use the resulting structure then you may get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

My apologies. I missed your final paragraph that explained how an item may have a spurious parent "1" in addition to the real value. I've added some code to sanitise the original data and create a map `%parent` of every node to its true parent before building the graph

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Graph::Directed;

my @arr = (

    #subways, "0" - superroot
    { id => "1", parent_id => "0", name => "subway 1" },

    #lines
    { id => "12642", parent_id => "1", name => "no category" },
    { id => "12645", parent_id => "1", name => "line 1" },

    #cars
    { id => "12646", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 1" },
    { id => "12646", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 1" },
    { id => "12647", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 2" },
    { id => "12647", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 2" },
    { id => "12679", parent_id => "1",     name => "separate cars" },
    { id => "12679", parent_id => "12642", name => "separate cars" },
    { id => "12643", parent_id => "1",     name => "ungrouped" },
    { id => "12643", parent_id => "12642", name => "ungrouped" }
);

# Sanitise data to remove "1" parents
#
my %parent;

for my $node ( @arr ) {
    my ($id, $parent_id) = @{$node}{qw/ id parent_id /};
    next unless $parent_id;
    $parent{$id} = $parent_id unless $parent{$id} and $parent{$id} ne 1;
}

# Build the graph
#
my $tree = Graph::Directed->new;

for my $node ( keys %parent ) {
    $tree->add_edge( $parent{$node} => $node );
}

# Display the data
#
my %names = map { @{$_}{qw/ id name /} } @arr;

print_tree($tree, $_) for $tree->predecessorless_vertices;

sub print_tree {
    my ($tree, $root, $indent) = @_;
    $indent //= 0;

    printf "%s%s\n",  '    ' x $indent, $names{$root};

    print_tree($tree, $_, $indent + 1) for $tree->successors($root);
}
```

#### output

```
subway 1
    line 1
        carriage 1
        carriage 2
    no category
        separate cars
        ungrouped
```

#### Original answer

I suggest that you make use of the [`Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph) module. A tree is a *directed* graph, and all you need to do is create a graph, add the connections ("edges") and interrogate the result

This program does exactly that. I have written a `print_tree` subroutine which displays the tree in indented lines from a given starting point. A call to `predecessorless_vertices` finds all the roots of the tree: nodes which no other node connects to. In this case there is just one root, as there should be

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Graph::Directed;

my @arr = (

    #subways, "0" - superroot
    { id => "1", parent_id => "0", name => "subway 1" },

    #lines
    { id => "12642", parent_id => "1", name => "no category" },
    { id => "12645", parent_id => "1", name => "line 1" },

    #cars
    { id => "12646", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 1" },
    { id => "12646", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 1" },
    { id => "12647", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 2" },
    { id => "12647", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 2" },
    { id => "12679", parent_id => "1",     name => "separate cars" },
    { id => "12679", parent_id => "12642", name => "separate cars" },
    { id => "12643", parent_id => "1",     name => "ungrouped" },
    { id => "12643", parent_id => "12642", name => "ungrouped" }
);

# Build the graph
#
my $tree = Graph::Directed->new;

for my $node ( @arr ) {
    $tree->add_edge( @{$node}{qw/ parent_id id /} ) if $node->{parent_id};
}

# Display the structure
#
my %names = map { @{$_}{qw/ id name /} } @arr;

print_tree($tree, $_) for $tree->predecessorless_vertices;

sub print_tree {
    my ($tree, $root, $indent) = @_;
    $indent //= 0;

    printf "%s%s\n",  '    ' x $indent, $names{$root};

    print_tree($tree, $_, $indent + 1) for $tree->successors($root);
}
```

#### output

```
subway 1
    no category
        ungrouped
        separate cars
    carriage 2
    carriage 1
    separate cars
    ungrouped
    line 1
        carriage 2
        carriage 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( current_sub say );

my @rows = (
   #subways, "0" - superroot
   {id => "1",     parent_id => "0",     name => "subway 1"},
   #lines
   {id => "12642", parent_id => "1",     name => "no category"},
   {id => "12645", parent_id => "1",     name => "line 1"},
   #cars
   {id => "12646", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 1"},
   {id => "12646", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 1"},
   {id => "12647", parent_id => "1",     name => "carriage 2"},
   {id => "12647", parent_id => "12645", name => "carriage 2"},
   {id => "12679", parent_id => "1",     name => "separate cars"},
   {id => "12679", parent_id => "12642", name => "separate cars"},
   {id => "12643", parent_id => "1",     name => "ungrouped"},
   {id => "12643", parent_id => "12642", name => "ungrouped"}
);

my $tree = { name => "[root]", children => [] };
{
   my %tree = ( 0 => $tree );

   for my $row (@rows) {
      my $node = $tree{ $row->{id} } //= { name => undef, children => [] };
      $node->{name} = $row->{name};

      my $parent_node = $tree{ $row->{parent_id} } //= { name => undef, children => [] };
      push @{ $parent_node->{children} }, $node;
   }
}

# Add depth to nodes.
# use a breadth-first search so that the depth of nodes
# at multiple depths are set to the node's deepest depth.
{
   my @todo = ( [ $tree, 0 ] );
   while (@todo) {
      my ($node, $depth) = @{ shift(@todo) };
      $node->{depth} = $depth;

      ++$depth;
      push @todo, map { [ $_, $depth ] } @{ $node->{children} };
   }
}

# Trim shortcuts to deeper nodes.
{
   my @todo = $tree;
   while (@todo) {
      my $node = shift(@todo);
      my $depth = delete($node->{depth}) + 1;
      @{ $node->{children} } = grep { $_->{depth} == $depth } @{ $node->{children} };
      push @todo, @{ $node->{children} };
   }
}

# Display tree
my $visitor = sub {
   my ($node, $depth) = @_;
   say "  " x $depth, $node->{name};
   __SUB__->($_, $depth+1) for @{ $node->{children} };
};

$visitor->($_, 0) for @$tree;
```

Output:

```
subway 1
  no category
    separate cars
    ungrouped
  line 1
    carriage 1
    carriage 2
```